# AxiosError 'Request failed with status code 404'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, mern

I made a form that returns a post as an object and dispatches it to actions/posts.js but running into an error on my browser's web console stated as

> POST http://localhost:5000/posts 404 (Not Found)

> form.js

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      dispatch(createPost(postData));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

i think it has something to do with createPost but cant figure out what as i am new to this.

> actions/posts.js

```
export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await api.createPost(post);
  
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE', payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

> api/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:5000/posts';

export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(url);
export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);
```

> reducers/posts.js

```
export default ( posts = [], action ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload;

        case 'CREATE':
            return [ ...posts, action.payload];

        default:
            return posts;   
    }
};
```

my back-end is

```
import express from 'express'; 
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'; 
import mongoose from 'mongoose'; 
import cors from 'cors';

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true })) 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true })) 
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);

const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://my username,password'; 
const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL,   {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true   } ) 
.then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port: http://localhost:${PORT}`))) .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

> backend routes

```
import express from 'express';

import { getPosts, createPosts } from '../controllers/posts.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', getPosts);
router.get('/create', createPosts);


export default router;
```

i have been following this tutorial of build and deploy an app using MERN.
youtube link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngc9gnGgUdA&list=PL6QREj8te1P7VSwhrMf3D3Xt4V6_SRkhu&index=19&t=1528s

i tried searching on google what the problem on google but cant figure out the solution. pls help !

Comment: Can you post your end-point route setup/declaration from the back-end?

Comment: @lpizzinidev i added my back-end does this suffice or should i add my routes too !

Comment: The backend routes are missing.

Comment: @madflow should i post controllers too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`POST http://localhost:5000/posts 404 (Not Found)` does not work, because you are defining the backend routes with  "GET".

The express [router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) adheres to [HTTP verbs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

```
// GET method route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage')
})

// POST method route
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage')
})
```

So

```
router.get('/', getPosts);
router.get('/create', createPosts);
```

should probably be:

```
router.get('/', getPosts);
router.post('/create', createPosts);
```

Fetching posts in the frontend code should then use the "get" verb, and creating posts should use the "post" verb.

Comment: Thanks that solves it ! such a dumb mistake. was following web console for pointing out error in client side with my 2 brain cells. cant even follow a tutorial right.